# PHP Wrong DateTime (DST)?

Tags: php, datetime

I have to return the current month, and the previous month.

Today, 31st of March, the two months are the same. (DST)

```
ini_set( 'date.timezone', 'Europe/Brussels' );

$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Brussels'));

$thisYearMonth = $now->format('Y-m');
$prevYearMonth = $now->modify('-1 month')->format('Y-m');
```

Both return '2014-03'.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because February has fewer days, so you need to apply some date magic:

```
$prevYearMonth = $now->modify('first day of last month')->format('Y-m');
```